# Android - Application background using styles.xml

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to set the background globally in the styles.xml using the following code

styles.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" >      
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background</item>      
  </style>
</resources>
```

I have also added it in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

....
</application>
```

But the image is not getting displayed. I have images in all the drawable folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<style name="Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
</style>
```

Comment: The issue was something different. I had to put in values-14 folder to get the image.

Ensure to put the styling in values-11 and values-14 folders as well.